# Remove then add query string values

Tags: html, razor, query-string

So my issue is i need to remove one parameter from a query string and then add another parameter in that same query string.

```
@Request.RemoveQueryStringKeyValue(value1)
<a href="@Request.AppendQueryStringKeyValue(name, value2)">link Name</a>
```

the problem is both of these return sepereate strings does anyone know of a better way of doing this? trying to avoid removing parameters from string index locations

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being doing this on the controller then just access it on the view.

```
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.AppendQueryStringKeyValue(name, value2);
quertString.Remove(value1);
dataItem.editedQueryString =  HttpUtility.UrlDecode(queryString.ToString());
```